# How to smooth polygon mesh in ARKit?

Tags: 3d, scenekit, augmented-reality, blender, 3d-modelling

I have this problem that when I display the 3D object (in my case the aircraft seen in the picture) it doesn't look smooth. Instead, it looks polygonally. I tried smoothing it in Blender but still doesn't work.

Any advice of why this happens? It is a problem when exporting .dae file in Blender?

[image: Aircraft]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I am certainly no expert, it could be an issue with the shading which has been applied to your model within Blender.

> When some models have their shading set to flat. .Flat shading makes the model look very blocky and unrealistic.

[image]

As such if you change this setting then your problem may be solved:

[image]

You can read more about how to do this [AppCode Tutorial](https://medium.com/appcoda-tutorials/realistic-rendering-of-3d-photogrammetry-model-in-arkit-a2ebec48e923)

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried the method you said, but didn't work. It still looks blocky. I don't know if it an Xcode thing.